# Using a thread to show a progress dialog in Android

Tags: android, multithreading, progressdialog

Here is a few bit of code:

```
public class ShowDialog extends Thread {
private static String mTitle="Please wait";
private static String mText="Loading...";
private Activity mActivity;
private ProgressDialog mDialog;

ShowDialog(Activity activity) {
    this(activity, mTitle, mText);
}
ShowDialog(Activity activity, String title) {
    this(activity, title, mText);
}
ShowDialog(Activity activity, String title, String text) {
    super();
    mText=text;
    mTitle=title;
    mActivity=activity;
    if (mDialog == null) {
        mDialog = new ProgressDialog(mActivity);
        mDialog.setTitle(mTitle);
        mDialog.setMessage(mText);
        mDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        mDialog.setCancelable(true);
        mDialog.setOnCancelListener(
            new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCancel(DialogInterface arg0) {
                    mDialog.dismiss();
                    interrupt();
                }
            });
    }
}

public void run() {
    mDialog.show();
    while(!isInterrupted())
    mDialog.dismiss();
    mDialog=null;
}
```

}

And in my main activity:

```
ShowDialog show = new ShowDialog(this, "Please wait!","Loading badly...");
    show.start();
    SystemClock.sleep(2000);
    show.interrupt();
```

I know I might use an async task and all the stuff but that is not what I want. Replace the SystemClock.sleep by anything that takes some time. The idea is to execute the code between start and interrupt in the UI thread and make a seperate thread handling the ProgressDialog.
What's wrong with my thread ?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To wait for a Thread to complete, you should use the `Thread.join()` method.  But now I see you're not wanting to wait for it to complete, but you need to control when it completes.  Still, you want to avoid interrupting threads in this fashion.

In your `ShowDialog` class, add a `dismiss()` method that you can call from your `main`, instead of `interrupt()`.  Also add a `boolean dismiss = false` instance variable.  In `dismiss()`, add `dismiss = true`, then `notify();`.  In `run()`, replace your constant `while()` loop (was running constantly, and very inefficient) with `while(!dismiss){wait()}`.  You will still need to add synchronization blocks and exception handling, but this should get you off to a good start.

Here is a generic-Java (non-android) simplified example:

```
public static class ShowDialog extends Thread{

    protected boolean dismiss;

    public void dismiss(){
        dismiss = true;
        synchronized(this){
            notifyAll();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run(){
        System.out.println("Running...");
        // Show your dialog here.
        while(!dismiss){
            synchronized(this){
                try{
                    wait();
                }catch(InterruptedException ie){
                    ie.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Quitting...");
        // Dismiss your dialog here.
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    ShowDialog sd = new ShowDialog();
    sd.start();
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    sd.dismiss();
}
```

You mentioned you didn't want to use `AsyncTask`, but I would still reconsider.  (What are your reasons against it?)

Comment: @Flav - No, call `show.join()` instead of your `sleep` statement.  But now I see better what you're trying to do here.  Updated answer to follow...